# CreateDocumentQuery crashes my app running local only

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, azure-cosmosdb

I have a ASP.Net Core MVC web app that is connecting to Azure Cosmos DB. I have a couple of CreateDocumentQuery statements that when I run my app locally, causes an exception and the running app to stop. When I publish the same code to my Azure site, it works just fine.

The line it seems to fail on is

```
var applicantJobs = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ApplicantJob>(documentCollectionUri).Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
```

The exception I get is [image]

Locally I can run CreateDocumentAsync and ReadDocumentAsync just fine with no issues.

I have read online about 64 vs 32 and have followed that guidance, but I assume I am missing something.

Comment: What nuget package and version are you using? Are you compiling in x64 by any chance?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I have Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.1 and Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Cod 1.3.1. I am targeting .NetCoreApp 1.1 and my platform target is x64. I also have Use the 64 bit version of IIS express for web sites and projects checked in VS2017/Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/WebProjects.

Comment: If you are targetting .NetCoreApp, did you try the [NetStandard package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core) instead?

Comment: yes, I miss typed in my comment about Core as Cod. I will try removing the DocumentDB 1.14.1 and see if that helps at all.

Comment: You shouldn't need both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the reference to Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.1 allows it to run successfully on my development machine.